# Perl Regex to get the root domain of a URL

Tags: regex, perl

How could I get some part of url?

For example:

```
http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx
http://www.stackoverflow.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I need to take just this part:

```
facebook.com
stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Remember that you can delimit regexes with other characters besides the slash. For example, to match everything up to the first slash: `$url =~ m{.*?/}`.

Comment: Unless you really need regex, u can think about the answer from ikegami.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just some simple regex stuff.

```
$facebook = "www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx";

$facebook =~ s/www\.(.*\.com).*/$1/; # get what is between www. and .com

print $facebook;
```

**Returns**

```
facebook.com
```

You may also want to make this work for `.net`, `.org`, etc. Something like:

```
s/www\.(.*\.(?:net|org|com)).*/$1/;
```

Comment: This is **Very hard** to get right with a single regex.  You really have to be careful.  What if it is `http` or `https` protocol.  What if there is no `www.`.  What if there is a URL like, https://mobile.google.com/a/b.  The check for the slash in the regex is greedy.  You can fix some of these issues, but you will probably get bitten by a regex.  This is a decent answer and solves the problem for the sample input, but not all possible URLs...

Answer (score 12):

```
use feature qw( say state );

use Domain::PublicSuffix qw( );
use URI                  qw( );

# Returns "domain.tld" for "subdomain.domain.tld". 
# Handles multi-level TLDs such as ".co.uk".
sub root_domain {
   my ($domain) = @_;
   state $parser = Domain::PublicSuffix->new();
   return $parser->get_root_domain($domain);
}

# Accepts urls as strings and as URI objects.
sub url_root_domain {
   my ($abs_url) = @_;
   my $domain = URI->new($abs_url)->host();
   return root_domain($domain);
}

say url_root_domain('http://www.facebook.com/');       # facebook.com
say url_root_domain('https://www.facebook.com/');      # facebook.com
say url_root_domain('http://mobile.google.com/');      # google.com
say url_root_domain('http://www.theregister.co.uk/');  # theregister.co.uk
say url_root_domain('http://www.com/');                # www.com
```

Comment: We do not know if the OP wants sub-domains or the root domain.  Should the answer be `mobile.google.com` or `google.com`?  It is not clear in the question.

Comment: If you have the domain in the form: "subdomain.domain.tld" you can get "domain.tld" with:      
`state $parser = Domain::PublicSuffix->new(); $parser->get_root_domain($subdomain_domain_tld);` (which is what ikegami explained but without the need to parse an URL). Thanks ikegami.

Answer (score 3):

This Might be helpful...

`^https?:\/\/www\.([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)`

**Sample Input:**

```
http://www.banglanews24.com/detailsnews.php
nssl=763daee77dc90b1c1baf0a361be2ff3c&nttl=20130416072403189462

http://www.prothom-alo.com/detail/date/2013-04-20/news/3463

http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx

http://www.stackoverflow.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

**Sample output:**

```
banglanews24.com

prothom-alo.com

facebook.com

stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the URI answer.  The OP requested a regex, so in honor of the request and as a challenge, here is the answer I came up with.  To be fair, sometimes it is not easy or feasible to install a CPAN modules.  I have worked on some projects that are hardened using a very specific version of Perl and only certain modules are allowed.

Here is my attempt at the regex answer.  Note that the `www.` is optional.  Sub-domains like `mobile.` are honored.  The search for `/` is not greedy therefore a URL with directories on the end will be parsed correctly.  I am not dependent on the protocol; it could be `http, https, file, sftp` whatever.  The output is captured in `$1`.

```
^.*://(?:[wW]{3}\.)?([^:/]*).*$
```

Sample input:

```
http://WWW.facebook.com:80/
http://facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/aaaaa
http://www.stackoverflow.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/aaaaaaa
https://mobile.yahoo.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/aaaaaaa
http://www.theregister.co.uk/
```

Sample output:

```
facebook.com
facebook.com
stackoverflow.com
mobile.yahoo.com
theregister.co.uk
```

**EDIT:** Thanks @ikegami for the extra challenge.  :)  Now it supports `WWW` in any mixed case and a port number like `:80`.

Comment: @ikegami, Fixed!  Any other fails you can see?  (Aside from the sub-domain and the fact that regexes start to get `ugly`)  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
my @urls = qw( http://www.facebook.com http://www.sadas.com/ );
for my $url (@urls) {
   $url =~ s/^https?:(?:www\.)?//ig;
   $url =~ s{/.*}{};
   print "$url\n";
}
```

Comment: What about `http://mobile.google.com/`? `https://www.facebook.com/`? `HTTP://www.facebook.com/`? `http://www.com/`? `http://www3.com/`?

Comment: (Works for `https://www.facebook.com/` `HTTP://www.facebook.com/` and `http://www3.com/` now. Fundamental design flaws prevent fixes for the others.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a="http://www.stackoverflow.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
if($a=~/\/\/\w+\.(.*)\// )
{   print $1; }
else
{ print "false";  }
```