# regex matching urls that contain string in relative path not in domain

Tags: ruby, regex, url

This is one of my interview questions. I didn't come up with a good enough solution and got rejected.

The question was

```
What is the one regex to match all urls that contain job(case insensitive) in the relative   
path(not domain) in the following list:

    - http://www.glassdoor.com/job/ABC
    - https://glassdoor.com/job/
    - HTTPs://job.com/test
    - Www.glassdoor.com/foo/bar/joBs
    - http://192.168.1.1/ABC/job
    - http://bankers.jobs/ABC/job
```

My solution was using `lookahead` and `lookbehind`, **`/(?<!\.)job(?!\.)/i`**. This works fine in above lists. However, if the url is `HTTPs://jobs.com/test`, it will not work.

I am wondering what is the correct answer for this question. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: For a full URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: Wow, never thought there are people who would test you on your regex skills ... Anyways, it depends on the language you're using. If you're using PCRE you might use `(?im)^(?://|[^/])++/(?=.*job).*$`, [see demo](http://regex101.com/r/aM3kQ8). In ruby `^(?:\/\/|[^\/])++\/(?=.*job).*$`, [see demo](http://rubular.com/r/fWhbEYsG9Z)

Comment: Another full URL example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15640775/1804678

Comment: HamZa: Why would you not test on regex skills?  Regexes are a programming language on their own, and if the job requires frequent use of regexes, it's perfectly reasonable to test a candidate's proficiency.

Comment: @HamZa Could you please explain the meaning of `++`, I understand one `+` means one and unlimited times. So what's meaning of `++`?

Comment: @AndyLester I would love to have a job full of regexes :)

Comment: @mitchelllc It's a possessive quantifier, it doesn't backtrack. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1117467) out

Comment: @Andy Lester - The problem is not the regex skill test, its the tester's skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/:\n]+\/.*?job
```

[**Online RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/d9PP8I/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?`: Match optional `http://` or `https://`
- `[^\/:]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not `/` and `:`
- `\/`: Match a `/`
- `.*?job`:  Match 0 or more characters followed by text `job`

Comment: I believe this link is not valid anymore

Comment: @dangel: I have updated answer with new demo and details.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to validate the url, just focus on 'job'

```
 #  /(?i)(?<=\/)job(?=\/|[^\S\r\n]*$)/

 (?i)
 (?<= / )
 job
 (?= / | [^\S\r\n]* $ )
```

Comment: This answer might be more efficient than the others because it does not have to parse a valid URL first.

Comment: @Jess - Yep, there is a URL regex about 20K bytes to do that I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that I came up with:

```
^(?:.*://)?(?:[wW]{3}\.)?([^:/])*/.*job.*
```

It matches all of your examples, but not the ones with job.com or jobs.com.  (jobs is only in the path.)

I tested this in sublime text which is nice b/c the regex result is highlighted as you type.

Answer (score 0):

i was also asked this question during the interview and here is my solution:
/.*/+job/?.*/i it works well on Rubular.com